# Diagnosing: random system freezes in Ubuntu 19.10 (Gnome)

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, freeze, 19.10

I'm really struggling with random system freezes. This typically involves either a 'full freeze' where the mouse still moves, but otherwise no interaction is possible (hard restart), or a 'partial freeze' where the mouse becomes unresponsive, but the keyboard still works, including application switching (switch to terminal, sudo reboot).

I haven't discovered any pattern as to why this might be. How can I diagnose what the problem is?

Comment: Look for .crash files in /var/crash. Look for clues around the time of a freeze in /var/log/syslog. Run Memtest (look it up) to check for faulty RAM.

Comment: Thank you! It actually looks as it is not a full system freeze, but rather the keyboard failing. For example, when there's music playing, it continues playing.